# Is it possible to display lines with text + icons in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, notifications

I would like to display different lines with notifications in a `ListView`.

[image]

I've tried a `StackPanel`, but I'm not sure whether I'm on the right path.

```
<StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="DarkBlue" Height="28">
   <Image Source="../Resources/crown.png" Height="18"/>
   <TextBlock Text="Hello, I am a text block!" Margin="3 0 0 0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It's not always the same lines, it can also be just text.

Does anyone have an idea how I can implement something like this (maybe also in code-behind)?

Comment: What are your data structures for the data (date/time, text, icons, one content line in general, ...)? If we do not know the data that you want to display it is hard to guess what would be an appropriate solution.

Comment: Think in terms of a list of lineviewmodel. A lineviewmodel has a property which is a list of object.  I would make each line an itemscontrol. With an itemspanel which is a horizontal stackpaneel. Define two datatemplates. One is a textblock. Another an image. Corresponding viewmodels. Exposing text in one and a url from the other. These are the objects above. You translate whatever data you have line by line into text... Picture source... Text. Etc.

Comment: @thatguy There is no data structure yet. I want to display text and images on one line, dynamically. Here I just don't know exactly how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any data structure, so let us create them in the following. This approach is not complete and there are just **too much options** to implement this scenario. You can adapt, improve and extend the examples to fit your requirements at any point.

I will use an `ItemsControl`, because this seems to be a read-only notification control. If you want the items to be selectable, you can easily replace it with a `ListBox` or a `ListView`.

The idea is easy, there is a `Line` model that contains all information to be displayed, which is a property of type `DateTime` for the timestamp and an enumerable of `LineFragment`, which represents all the distinct data types that are displayed in a line.

```
public class Line
{
   public Line(DateTime dateTime, IEnumerable<LineFragment> fragments)
   {
      DateTime = dateTime;
      Fragments = fragments;
   }

   public DateTime DateTime { get; }

   public IEnumerable<LineFragment> Fragments { get; }
}
```

`LineFragment` is the base type for a lot of derived types that represent text and other data in one line.

```
public abstract class LineFragment
{
}
```

- A simple `TextFragment` represents plain text in a line.

  ```
  public class TextFragment : LineFragment
  {
     public TextFragment(string text)
     {
        Text = text;
     }

     public string Text { get; }
  }
  ```
- A player fragment that represents a player, e.g. *Knochenbrecher Messerkämpferin*.

  ```
  public class PlayerFragment : LineFragment
  {
     public PlayerFragment(string name)
     {
        Name = name;
     }

     public string Name { get; }
  }
  ```
- A player status fragement that represents the skulls and crowns in braces.

  ```
  public class PlayerStatFragment : LineFragment
  {
     public PlayerStatFragment(int skulls, int crowns)
     {
        Skulls = skulls;
        Crowns = crowns;
     }

     public int Skulls { get; }

     public int Crowns { get; }
  }
  ```
- An attribute stat fragment that has derivatives that represent attributes like *Glory*, *Experience* or *Silver*.

  ```
  public abstract class AttributeStatFragment : LineFragment
  {
     protected AttributeStatFragment(string name, AttributeStatOperator statOperator, int value)
     {
        Name = name; 
        Operator = statOperator;
        Value = value;
     }

     public string Name { get; }

     public AttributeStatOperator Operator { get; }

     public int Value { get; }
  }

  public class GloryStatFragment : AttributeStatFragment
  {
     public GloryStatFragment(string name, AttributeStatOperator statOperator, int value) : base(name, statOperator, value)
     {
     }
  }

  public class ExperienceStatFragment : AttributeStatFragment
  {
     public ExperienceStatFragment(string name, AttributeStatOperator statOperator, int value) : base(name, statOperator, value)
     {
     }
  }

  public class SilverStatFragment : AttributeStatFragment
  {
     public SilverStatFragment(string name, AttributeStatOperator statOperator, int value) : base(name, statOperator, value)
     {
     }
  }

  public enum AttributeStatOperator
  {
     Plus,
     Minus
  }
  ```
- A tax fragment and derivatives that represent taxes like *Guild Tax*.

  ```
  public abstract class TaxFragment : LineFragment
  {
     public TaxFragment(string name, int value)
     {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
     }

     public string Name { get; }

     public int Value { get; }
  }

  public class GuildTaxFragment : TaxFragment
  {
     public GuildTaxFragment(string name, int tax) : base(name, tax)
     {
     }
  }
  ```

Now you can expose a collection of `Line`s in your view model or code-behind. If you are adding items at runtime you have to use an [`ObervableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0), otherwise changes like adding, removing or inserting items will not be reflected in the user interface.

```
public ObservableCollection<Line> Lines { get; }
```

Do not forget to initialize the collection property. After that you can add your items like this:

```
Lines.Add(new Line(DateTime.Now, new List<LineFragment>
{
   new TextFragment("Du hast"),
   new GloryStatFragment(GloryStatName, AttributeStatOperator.Plus, 820),
   new PlayerStatFragment(390, 273),
   new TextFragment("erhalten")
}));

Lines.Add(new Line(DateTime.Now, new List<LineFragment>
{
   new TextFragment("Du erhältst"),
   new ExperienceStatFragment(ExperienceStatName, AttributeStatOperator.Plus, 42)
}));

Lines.Add(new Line(DateTime.Now, new List<LineFragment>
{
   new PlayerFragment("Knochenbrecher Messerkämpferin"),
   new TextFragment("hat"),
   new TextFragment("für dich regeneriert")
}));

Lines.Add(new Line(DateTime.Now, new List<LineFragment>
{
   new TextFragment("Du hast"),
   new SilverStatFragment(SilverStatName, AttributeStatOperator.Plus, 184),
   new PlayerStatFragment(75, 61),
   new TextFragment("erhalten")
}));

Lines.Add(new Line(DateTime.Now, new List<LineFragment>
{
   new TextFragment("Du hast"),
   new GuildTaxFragment(GuildTaxName, 46),
   new TextFragment("bezahlt")
}));
```

In order to display the fragments, we have to create `DataTemplate`s for our items in XAML. Please note that I have created dummy images that are located in the `Resources` folder for demonstration purposes.

```
<Style x:Key="LineFragmentImageStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
   <Setter Property="Width"
           Value="10" />
   <Setter Property="Height"
           Value="10" />
   <Setter Property="Margin"
           Value="2" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="OperatorTextBlockStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="Text"
           Value="+ " />
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                   Value="{x:Static local:AttributeStatOperator.Minus}">
         <Setter Property="Text"
                 Value="- " />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextFragment}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PlayerFragment}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PlayerStatFragment}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="( " />
      <Image Source="Resources/skull.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Skulls, StringFormat='{} {0} '}" />
      <Image Source="Resources/crown.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Crowns, StringFormat='{} {0} '}" />
      <TextBlock Text=" ) " />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ExperienceStatFragment}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Operator}"
                 Style="{StaticResource OperatorTextBlockStyle}" />
      <Image Source="Resources/key.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{} {0} '}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GloryStatFragment}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Operator}"
                 Style="{StaticResource OperatorTextBlockStyle}" />
      <Image Source="Resources/badge.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{} {0} '}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SilverStatFragment}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Operator}"
                 Style="{StaticResource OperatorTextBlockStyle}" />
      <Image Source="Resources/silver.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{} {0} '}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GuildTaxFragment}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="Resources/silver.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{} {0} '}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0} '}" />
      <TextBlock Text="(" />
      <Image Source="Resources/armor.png"
             Style="{StaticResource LineFragmentImageStyle}" />
      <TextBlock Text=")" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then we create a data template for the `Line` itself. Each line displays a timestamp with a `TextBlock` next to an `ItemsControl` that shows all fragments horizontally using the data templates defined above. The `WrapPanel` will automatically wrap a line if it exceeds the viewport.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Line}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                 Margin="3"
                 Text="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=[hh:mm:ss]}" />
      <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="3"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Fragments}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Last but not least, to show the `Lines` collection, we have to add an `ItemsControl` to our user interface XAML that uses the `Line` data template to display the lines.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" Style="{StaticResource LinesItemsControlStyle}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

And that is it. You can extend it with other items easily. This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot of application (left), with fragment wrapping (right).]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. That helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Images actually inside the text (like an emoticon), then you are going to have to do some work. This sounds like one of the few times I would actually want a User Control, the point of which would be one that scans the Text looking for emoticon values and building a Data Template on the fly.

Remember that anything you can do in XAML you can do in code, so the code I'm thinking of would follow this general idea:

1. Scan text for emoticon values and create a list of values for data elements.
2. Create a DockPanel.
3. Foreach element in the List, add either a TextBlock or an Image (based on value).
4. Set this.Content to the DockPanel.

I think something like this is actually what you are looking for, but if you want just an Image, then the ValueConverter suggestion would work.

Comment: What it has to do with the question?

Comment: she want to add image to her test. that what i explain how to do